# What is the difference between a hex decoded string and a string.as_bytes()?

Tags: string, rust, binary, hex, byte

I am hashing a string.

```
let src = String::from("abcd12342020");
let h1 = sha2::Sha256::digest(&src.as_bytes());
let h2 = sha2::Sha256::digest(hex::decode(&src).expect("this is not hex"));
```

`h1` and `h2` are different. What is the *underlying* reason? What is the difference between a bytes representation and the hex decoded one?
(Tried to provide a playground but the `hex` create is not available there)

Comment: Just popping in here: "lack of research effort" is a valid downvote reason (its on the hover text). [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3257622) - doing your own troubleshooting and debugging is expected.

Comment: Well you won't believe but I did. The decode docs just say "decode into raw bytes", while `as_bytes` says " Returns a byte slice of this `String`'s contents". That doesn't give a hint about the actual difference. At least I didn't get it. Also, there are heavily upvoted questions like "how to extract the OK result", which you can just go and see in the docs. Seems to me different measuring sticks are used at times.

Comment: I'm just trying to provide an explanation. And yes SO is far from uniform, it is community managed and votes are cast at individual users' discretion. The silver lining is that simple questions often attract upvotes given time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`h1` and `h2` are different because `src.as_bytes()` and `hex::decode(&src)` are different. Wrap them with the `dbg!` macro to see the difference.

They're different because `hex::decode` parses the text as hex, meaning `ab` gets parsed into `0xAB` etc. But `src.as_bytes()` returns the text encoded as a UTF-8 byte sequence, meaning `ab` is encoded in memory as `[0x61, 0x62]`.

Comment: I can see they are different. The second part was what I was aiming at. Thanks.